# facebook return proxy email instead of primary email starting 7/2/2013

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Starting today, when calling "/me" of new users to my app, the users details I am getting include the facebook proxy email address.
In the permissions requested, I am asking for user_about_me,publish_stream,email,user_location,friends_birthday,user_birthday,publish_actions.

What could cause it?
I must mention that until February 6th 2013 changes were added, it worked fine....

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I have a a Rails application and allow people to signup via facebook. I ask for the following permissions: publish_stream, publish_actions, offline_access, email As of the 7th I only seem to get the facebook proxy email address. This is not part of the February breaking changes as far as I can tell. Anyone?